# MySQL ST_Contains with wrong result

Tags: mysql, polygon, contains, spatial

I'm using MySQL ST_Contains in order to find out if an area is contained in an other area. Therefore I have a table like this:

```
CREATE TABLE tablex (id int, geoPoly MULTIPOLYGON NOT NULL, SPATIAL INDEX(geoPoly))
```

in order to find out which areas are contained in a certain area, I use the following query:

```
SELECT b.* FROM tablex as a 
LEFT JOIN tablex as b  ON ST_CONTAINS(b.geoPoly, a.geoPoly) 
WHERE a.intID = 123
```

This works for most cases but with one special case it gives wrong answers:

I copied the geo-coords of Austrias region Bregenz and Mellau from openstreetmaps. Mellau is included in Bregenz. But the above query says that Mellau is included but not in Bregenz (which is simply not true). Both shapes use the same "way" as a common border on the left side and on the right side Bregenz is much bigger than Mellau

see it on map:
http://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/74231
vs.
http://www.openstreetmap.org/relation/75097

Unfortunately I cant post my coord-data here (stackoverflow just allows to post 30.000 chars). So the question is: How can I find out **why** mysql says it is not included?

thanks in advance!

Comment: PS: The query `SELECT b.* FROM tablex as a 
LEFT JOIN tablex as b  ON ST_intersects(b.geoPoly, a.geoPoly)  AND NOT ST_touches(b.geoPoly, a.geoPoly) 
WHERE a.intID = 123` returns the right result but needs 10 times more time. (also its not the best way)

Answer (score 1):

You can use ST_Buffer with a really small distance (the 0.0000001) (but not too small, be careful) and it'll work.
An example :

```
SELECT st_within(g1.shape, ST_buffer(geometrycollection(g1.shape, g2.shape), 0.0000001))
FROM (SELECT * FROM geoflas WHERE id = 1) as g1, 
    (SELECT * FROM geoflas WHERE id = 2) as g2;
```

Answer (score 0):

I would suggest that your polygon coordinates are probably slightly different along the shared line and hence the smaller area is not completely contained within the larger area.

If just one coordinate of the smaller polygon falls outside of the larger area (even at the 8th decimal point which you wouldn't see by eye!!!) some part of the small area will not be contained within the larger area and thus, you get the correct answer, but not necessarily the one you're looking for.

You should be able to use a combination of the Intersection and the Difference spatial function to find the problem - you will need to be able to project results on to a map to see where the problem lies.  See http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/spatial-operator-functions.html